# Can I find out how many extras are in a data object?

Tags: java, android, extras

I have an activity with some CheckBoxes and each box has a String value that is added to an ArrayList.  When the OK button is clicked a returnResult Intent is created and the extras are put to the intent.

In onActivityResult I want to create a for loop that iterates through the data object's extras and adds the Strings together.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String tmpString = "";
        if (resultCode == 2) {
            for(int i = 0;i<data.getExtras().size();i++)
                tmpString = tmpString.concat(); //Stuck here
            }
        } else {

        }
    }
```

How can I get an extra at position i in the data object?

Comment: Extra position `i`? If you're saying what I'm thinking, try a 2 dimensional `forloop`. Just add another loop inside that one, and set the inner loop to `i < 1` if you want it to loop the same amount of times as your current loop.

Comment: What I meant was to take the String at and add it to tmpString

Comment: You know you can put String Arrays and String ArrayLists into the extras, right? Then you would just need to get that one object and go through that.

Comment: You wanna take a value from the `ArrayList`, and add it to tempString? `tempString += tmpString.get(i);`. You can also do `+"\n"` after the get method, or something similar if you wanna separate each value

Comment: Ahh yes Pescis that's a better idea. Thanks